# Chaining nested asynchronous finds with Node.js monk and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

Using Node.js monk and MongoDB, I want to mimic a table join:

1. Do a find on collection A
2. For each result X, do a find in collection B, and update X
3. Return updated list of results

The asynchronous nature of database commands in monk is giving me trouble.
This is my initial code. It doesn't work because the second call to `find` returns a promise immediately,
and the results in `xs` are sent in the response before they can be updated.

```
var db = require('monk')('localhost/mydb');
db.get('collection').find({}, function(e,xs) {
  xs.forEach(function(x){
    coll_b.find({a_id:x._id}, function(e,bs) {
      a['bs'] = bs;
    });
  });
  res.json({'results':as});
});
```

I feel like I should use promise chaining here, but I cannot figure out how to do it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using a synchronous loop inside an asynchronous function. They haven't returned a result yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: That post is relevant but I don't feel it answers my question, and it is not a duplicate because my problem is that I need to perform further async queries, and subsequently update the results, before returning them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it in this way, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23069551/98600):

```
var db = require('monk')('localhost/mydb');

// Initial find
db.get('collection').find({}, function(e,xs) {

  // Get inner finds as a list of functions which return promises
  var tasks = xs.map(function(x){
    return function() {
      return coll_b.find({a_id:x._id}, function(e,bs) {
        a['bs'] = bs;
      });
    }
  });

  // Chain tasks together
  var p = tasks[0](); // start the first one
  for(var i = 1; i < tasks.length; i++) p = p.then(tasks[i]);

  // After all tasks are done, output results
  p.then(function(_x){
    res.json({'results':xs});
  });

});
```

I still feel like this code could be minimised by using `chain()`, but at least this works as expected.

**Note**: I realise that performing a second find for each result is not necessarily efficient, but that's not my concern here.