# How to make sure a variable amount of Promise returning functions is resolved?

Tags: node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I've got a problem structuring my async code. All database-operations are async and return Promises.

I need to find a bunch of Items in the database, change them, then save them and only after all have been saved, continue with the next step in my program flow.

How can I solve this using ES6 promises?

Here is some pseudo-code illustrating my problem:

```
 database.find("Items").then(results => {
   results.forEach(result => {
      result.name = "some different name";
      database.save(result) // <-- is also async as find
   });
   return true;
 }).then(next) {
   // Only start here after all database.save() have been resolved
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make this async foreach loop work with promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069380/how-do-i-make-this-async-foreach-loop-work-with-promises)

Comment: Are you unhappy with the answers you got? Either comment your thoughts or remaining issues, or react otherwise please

Comment: @Amit I was unhappy with how I posed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for multiple promises - it takes an array (of variable length) of promises.

```
database.find("Items").then(results => {
    var promises = results.map(result => {
//                         ^^^
        result.name = "some different name";
        return database.save(result);
//      ^^^^^^
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(saves => {
//      ^^^^^ an array of the results from the save operations
    …; // starts after all database.save() promises have been resolved
});
```

Comment: The `saves` callback is missing the arrow FYI.

Comment: @loganfsmyth & FelixKling: Thanks, I overlooked that when editing the OP code

Comment: I sometimes also get an Array-like object form the db `{'1': 'obj1', '2':'obj2'}` I need to traverse in the same way as above. I traverse it using `for..in`. How would I write that since there's no callback I can return of like with `.map()` ?

Comment: Just generate an array of promises in that loop. You don't need to use `Array map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
database.find("Items").then(results => {
   return Promise.all(results.map(result => {
      result.name = "some different name";
      return database.save(result) // <-- is also async as find
   }));
 }).then(() => {
   // Only start here after all database.save() have been resolved
 });
```